# PHP Format json file (Alternate between Pretty_Print and Compact one line)

Tags: php, json

json_decode has an option to "prettify" a json file;

```
$json = json_encode($file,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
```

This:

```
{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}
{"name":"Mary","age":20,"city":"New York"}
```

Becomes this:

```
{  
   "name":"John",
   "age":30,
   "city":"New York"
}
{  
   "name":"Mary",
   "age":20,
   "city":"New York"
}
```

Is there a way to reverse back to one line?

I have a function which loop through the file, where each line is an object.
So, if the file has pretty_print then obviously the function doesn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't put multiple JSON objects in a single file. Collect the objects into an array and encode that.

Comment: But if you're stuck with a file like this. a new object or array starts on every line that begins with `{` or `[`.

Comment: `preg_replace` on `[^}]?\n` or something.

Comment: And it ends on a line that begins with `}` or `]`. So you can loop over the lines, concatenating until you see a line that isn't indented. Then decode it.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! This helps, and should solve the problem. But it would be nice if there was a function that could reverse the process. Anyway!

Comment: `json_decode()` will do it, but with the caveat that it has to be a valid JSON document and not a JSON-ish-looking document.

Comment: @Sammitch hahaha so simple. Thank you!

Comment: Like I said above, you should avoid the problem in the first place by creating a valid JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, it's not advisable to put multiple JSON objects in a single file.
However, for some reason, if you need to do it; and you have a problem like mine, here is the solution.

As commented above, `json_decode()` does format a prettified json back to one line; however, a file with multiple json objects isn't a valid file. So, you can't get the whole thing and pass through `json_decode()`. And even if you could, you would have a single line with multiple objects, which only transfer the problem.

I found this function, and it works perfectly:

```
function json_split_objects($json)
{
    $q = FALSE;
    $len = strlen($json);
    for($l=$c=$i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
    {   
        $json[$i] == '"' && ($i>0?$json[$i-1]:'') != '\\' && $q = !$q;
        if(!$q && in_array($json[$i], array(" ", "\r", "\n", "\t"))){continue;}
        in_array($json[$i], array('{', '[')) && !$q && $l++;
        in_array($json[$i], array('}', ']')) && !$q && $l--;
        (isset($objects[$c]) && $objects[$c] .= $json[$i]) || $objects[$c] = $json[$i];
        $c += ($l == 0);
    }   
    return $objects;
}
```

And just use it like this:

```
$array = json_split_objects($json);
foreach($array as $arr){
    file_put_contents('file.json', $arr . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```